# How to Rerun failed Specs for a specific number of times in Protactor?

Tags: protractor

I have a **conf.js** file and and a **spec.js** file. In *spec.js* 5(five) `It{}` Blocks are present. On running it through protractor the 4th `It` Block sometime gets passed or sometime gets failed (due to network connectivity).Now how can I re-run my 4th `It` Block to a specific number of times so that I will get a pass result?

Answer (score 1):

There is a npm package - [protractor-flake](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-flake) which will exactly fit your need.This will take in the `--max-attempts=3` argument which will control the number of times failed tests would run.

Usage:

> npm i -g protractor-flake
>
> `protractor-flake --protractor-path=/path/to/protractor
>   --parser standard --node-bin node --max-attempts=3 --color=magenta -- path/to/protractor.conf.js`